# Incorporating preset values in ascii file writing Python

Tags: python, ascii, console.writeline

I am trying to incorporate preset values in my script for when I write to an ascii file, however I have not been able to find out how to do this. My preset values are string values pulled from a different file before.

```
XBenchmark = (find_line_and_column('zz_ssmv11034tS__T0001TTNATS2012021505HP001.Hdr', 49, 4))

YBenchmark = (find_line_and_column('zz_ssmv11034tS__T0001TTNATS2012021505HP001.Hdr', 50, 4))

Xaxis= (find_line_and_column('zz_ssmv11034tS__T0001TTNATS2012021505HP001.Hdr', 51, 3))

Yaxis = (find_line_and_column('zz_ssmv11034tS__T0001TTNATS2012021505HP001.Hdr', 52, 3))
```

I am trying to incorporate those preset values somehow in a file write similar to this.

```
f = open('zz_ssmv11034tS__T0001TTNATS2012021505HP001.Hdr','w')
f.writelines(['byteorder M\n', 'layout bil\n', 'nbands 1\n', 'nbits 16\n', 'ncols 6935\n''nrows (**Yaxis**)\n''ulxmap (**Xbenchmark**)\n''ulymap 52.8704166666666\n'])
f.close()
```

Comment: You could have a look at the `string.format` method

Comment: It may be jut me, but I don't understand what you want to achieve. Are asking about [string formatting](https://pyformat.info/) here? If so, from Python 3.6 you could even do `'ulxmap ({XBenchmark})\n'`.

Comment: I am asking how you would write a variable like XBenchmark into an ascii file.

Comment: What type of variable is `XBenchmark`, (what is type of value returned from `find_line_and_column`) ? It seems like it is a string, `str`, won't `file.write` write it to the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
f = open('zz_ssmv11034tS__T0001TTNATS2012021505HP001.Hdr','w')
        f.writelines(['byteorder M\n', 'layout bil\n', 'nbands 1\n', 'nbits 16\n', 'ncols '+ncols+'\n','nrows '+nrows+'\n','ulxmap '+XBenchmark+'\n','ulymap '+YBenchmark+'\n','xdim '+Xaxis+'\n','ydim '+Yaxis+'\n'])
        f.close()
```